# How does this svn script work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, subversion

I defined this bash function to update multiple `svn` projects with a single command:

```
svn_update_all () 
{ 
    repos=`find . -name '.svn'`;
    for i in "$repos";
    do
        svn update `dirname $i`;
        echo;
    done
}
```

The output it gives is:

```
Updating 'project1':
At revision 26713.
Updating 'project2':
At revision 26723.
Summary of updates:
  Updated 'project1' to r26713.
  Updated 'project2' to r26723.
```

The `Summary of updates` output is a little confusing. Each line is printed by a separate invocation of the program. How can there be a consolidated summary?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: those aren't separate invocations; you're only running `svn update` once.

(You can test that by running the function under `set -x`, which makes bash print every command as it is run: `set -x; svn_update_all; set +x`)

If you really want to run `svn` multiple times (and you're certain you will *never* have spaces in your paths), you can just drop the quotes around `$repos`:

```
svn_update_all ()
{ 
    repos=`find . -name '.svn'`
    for i in $repos
    do
        svn update `dirname $i`
        echo
    done
}
```

Here's the deal with `for` loops. `bash(1)` says:

> **for** *name* [ [ **in** [ *word* *...* ] ] ; ] **do** *list* ; **done**
>
> The list of words following **in** is expanded, generating a list of
>   items. The variable *name* is set to each element of this list in
>   turn, and *list* is executed each time.

So the contents of the `for` block runs once for each *word* after `in`. Here's an example:

```
count=0
for num in one two three; do
do
    let count++
    echo "loop $count: '$num'"
done
```

```
loop 1: 'one'
loop 2: 'two'
loop 3: 'three'
```

But *a quoted string* is taken as a *single word*. This is basically what's happening in your script:

```
count=0
for num in "one two three"; do
    let count++
    echo "loop $count: '$num'"
done
```

```
loop 1: 'one two three'
```

Remove the quotes and `$repos` gets split into separate words again, and then `svn update` gets run once for each repo, as you expected.

Note well, though: **this will break if you ever have a path that has spaces in it**.

The *simplest* way to handle paths that *might* have spaces is to pipe the output of `find` into the `read` builtin command:

```
find . -name '.svn' | while read i
do
    svn update `dirname $i`
    echo
done
```

The *safest* way is to use `find`'s `-exec` or `-execdir` actions, so you don't have to worry about `bash` splitting up filenames:

```
# print the repo dir, then run "svn update" in it
find . -name '.svn' -printf '%h: ' -execdir svn update \;
```

```
./mpc: Updating '.':
U    trunk/src/pow.c
U    trunk/tests/pow.dat
U    trunk/m4/mpc.m4
Updated to revision 1455.
./mpfr: Updating '.':
[etc]
```

Answer (score 0):

either remove quotes, or pipe trough for

for instance

```
for i in "a b"
do
echo $i
done
```

give as ouptut

```
a b
```

so most likely you end up with

```
svn update project1 project2
```

hence the summary.

try

```
find . -name '.svn' |
while read i
do
    svn update `dirname $i`;
    echo;
done
```